# Software to extract voice from a song

Tags: windows, audio

Requirements:

- Freeware or Commercial
- Works on Windows 8

I need to extract only vocals from a soundtrack. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is really hard to do, but with *some* sources you can get part of the way there. I doubt that you will find software that just does vocal extraction. So instead you will need to use a general-purpose editor and learn the necessary techniques with it.

My preferred free audio editor for tasks like this is [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) - it is freeware and open-source.

[Here is a tutorial on using Audacity to remove or isolate a vocal track](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html) - In some cases, you can just use a "Vocal removal" menu item or install a plugin to do what you want in a single click. However, bear in mind that it is not always possible to get good (or even vaguely useful) results.

Comment: Please see my answer. @Neil Slater

Answer (score 0):

I found a post [here](http://www.mymusictools.com/articles/how-to-extract-voice-from-a-song.htm).

A software named  AV Music Morpher Gold can do the job. But I doubt it.

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself. If you don't think the software can do the job then don't say that it can. Instead say that the software claims to be able to do the job, but you cannot confirm that it actually works.

Comment: Yes, in general it is better to recommend only software that you have tried yourself. Thanks for the tip though. If anyone could try it and then edit WD's answer or comment it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no software that could do that, but you can try find acappela version  on 
http://www.acapellas4u.co.uk/ Also there is tutorial on Youtube how in Ableton Live create  acapella version by combining full song and instrument together. Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

> [Spleeter](https://github.com/deezer/spleeter) is the Deezer source separation library with pretrained
> models written in Python and using Tensorflow. It makes it easy to
> train music source separation models (assuming you have a dataset of
> isolated sources), and provides already trained state of the art
> models for performing various flavours of separation.
>
> Spleeter is the Deezer source separation library with pretrained
> models written in Python and using Tensorflow. It makes it easy to
> train music source separation models (assuming you have a dataset of
> isolated sources), and provides already trained state of the art
> models for performing various flavours of separation.